# driver to fix "module ABI major version (1) doesn't match the server's version (5)" error

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, xorg, runtime-error

I have just upgraded from Slackware 12 to Slackware 13 (Linux) due to websites upgrading and the need for new browsers. But now I ran into a problem.

It seems I can use the standard vesa driver to load the X system (that controls all graphics) in Linux but if I replace it with the ATI rage chipset that I already have in my computer, the system won't start and I get this error:

```
(II) Module r128: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.3.0, module version = 4.1.0
    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 1.2
(EE) module ABI major version (1) doesn't match the server's version (5)
(II) UnloadModule: "r128"
(II) Unloading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers//r128_drv.so
(EE) Failed to load module "r128" (module requirement mismatch, 0)
(EE) No drivers available.
```

I did find several ATI drivers at:

https://www.x.org/releases/individual/driver/

But the question is how do I know which driver to install? How would I know the one I choose isn't too new or too old?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us your X server version, but according to [this list](https://www.x.org/wiki/XorgModuleABIVersions/), video driver version 5 corresponds to server version 1.6 (which is still pretty old).

Server version 1.6 seems to have been built around [2008/2009](https://www.x.org/wiki/Server16Branch/), which means I'd try r128 builds from around this time, which are e.g. 6.8.0 and 6.8.1.

If this doesn't match, you'll either have to look inside the downloaded files to see if the mention the driver ABI major version (e.g. in the man page), or you'll have to install it, try it, and binary search until it fits.

BTW, I can really recommend a distro with package management instead of using Slackware. The package dependencies will resolve problems like these for you automatically, saving you a lot of trouble and work (and saving other people the trouble to google it for you).

Comment: looking at the command line the version I have is 1.6.3 and X protocol 11 revision 0.

Comment: 1.6.3 counts as 1.6 for this purpose. The version of the X protocol is not relevant.

Comment: @dirkt Slackware has package management, please stop spreading FUD.